# Popular uma outra array com o resultado de uma busca

Tags: angular, npm

Preciso pegar a array de objetos após a busca que faço com ng2-search-filter.

Abaixo onde tenho o input da minha busca já funcionando, e quero passar o resultado toda vez que é digitada (keyup) alguma letra, no caso, só falta passar o resultado, no caso o "result", para poder trabalhar com ele no arquivo .ts

```
<div class="search-venda">
   <input class="form-control"  type="text"  [(ngModel)]="term" (keyup)="onKey($event, result)"  autocomplete="off" placeholder="Digite para pesquisar">
</div>
```

Faço a impressão dos dados em uma table com o *ngFor

```
 <tr  *ngFor="let submission of vendas | filter:term; ">
              <td>{{submission.cnpj}}</td>
              <td>{{submission.razao_social}}</td>
              <td>{{submission.funcionario}}</td> </tr>
```

Tudo funcionando, só gostaria do resultado da pesquisa ser colocada em uma array resultante para poder passar como parâmetro no (keyup) e trabalhar com esses valores no arquivo .ts, preciso disso pois preciso de calcular alguns valores com os resultados obtidos.